# how to ascribe (x,y) coordinates to text?

Tags: coordinate-systems

Greetings, Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can either, a) map text on a grid (what i imagine is a Cartesian system where each character has a (x,y) coordinate, or b) if a grid is not possible, somehow measure text for i)location of a character, difference (delta) between one text location and another x2-x1 horizontal or difference between one text location and another vertically y2-y1? I am on a PC and would require a suggested programming method or program suggestion (is there a PC based text program with this feature that anyone knows of)? Thanks so much in advance,
c~tea

Comment: Which O/S, programming language, and API[s] do you want to use?

Comment: This isn't the clearest question ever.  Do you mean "how can I obtain the x,y coordinates of the characters in a particular chunk of text, displayed in a particular font"?  So, if I display "This is a line of text", you want to be able to find the coordinates of "T", "h", "i", "s", and so on?

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a defined programming language, I suggest [PostScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript).

PostScript is a page description language which has the feature you ask. It is understood by many printers directly and for the rest there are interpreters. It is also the basis of the PDF file format. On the wikipedia page is an example that demonstrates the use of the coordinate system:

```
%!PS
/Courier             % name the desired font
20 selectfont        % choose the size in points and establish 
                     % the font as the current one
72 500 moveto        % position the current point at 
                     % coordinates 72, 500 (the origin is at the 
                     % lower-left corner of the page)
(Hello world!) show  % stroke the text in parentheses
showpage             % print all on the page
```

The coordinate system has its origin in the lower left corner and is measured in points (1/72 inch)